# How does this formula transform at a small time step

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Equation 1 is described in a book ("*Bayesian models: a statistical primer for ecologists*"):

**Equation 1**: $\log (\frac{{{N_t}}}{{{N_{t - 1}}}}) = ({\beta _0} + {\beta _1}{N_{t - 1}}) \cdot \Delta t$

where: ${{N_t}}$ is the abundance of animal in year $t$; $\beta $ is the parameter.

It is said that if we assume $\Delta t$ is small, then the expression becomes:

**Equation 2**: $\frac{1}{N} \cdot \frac{{dN}}{{dt}} = {\beta _0} - {\beta _1}N$

I tried to find the way from Equation 1 to Equation 2, below is my procedure:

(1) Because $\Delta t$ is small, so ${N_t} = {N_{t - 1}} + {\left. {\frac{{dN}}{{dt}}} \right|_{t = t - 1}} \cdot t$.

(2) So the left part of Equation 1 becomes: $\ln \frac{{{N_{t - 1}} + \frac{{dN}}{{dt}} \cdot \Delta t}}{{{N_{t - 1}}}} = \ln (1 + \frac{{dN}}{{dt}} \cdot \frac{1}{{{N_{t - 1}}}} \cdot t)$

(3) Because $\Delta t$ is very small, $\ln (1 + \frac{{dN}}{{dt}} \cdot \frac{1}{{{N_{t - 1}}}} \cdot t)\approx \frac{{dN}}{{dt}} \cdot \frac{1}{{{N_{t - 1}}}} \cdot t$

(4) Then Equation 1 becomes: $\frac{{dN}}{{dt}} \cdot \frac{1}{{{N_{t - 1}}}} \cdot t = ({\beta _0} + {\beta _1}{N_{t - 1}}) \cdot t$, which is: $\frac{{dN}}{{dt}} \cdot \frac{1}{{{N_{t - 1}}}} = ({\beta _0} + {\beta _1}{N_{t - 1}}) $

I went to the Step (4), this equation looks like Equation 2, but it is still different. I don't know why ${N_{t - 1}} $is still there; and why it is "+" instead of "-" before ${\beta _1} $?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only see the [preview chapter 1](https://press.princeton.edu/titles/10523.html). There on page 12 in the footnotes 12 and 13 the confusing story is told. 13 says that for statistical analysis and application of  regression procedures the operations in the linear combinations are all kept additions, even while $β_1$ is negative.

However, in footnote 12 the case $1/N\cdot dN/dt = r-rN/K$ is discussed, and for some unexplained reason, perhaps in continuity to some other source, and in contradiction to all other uses of it, the parameter is then taken as $β_1=r/K$, so that indeed then $1/N\cdot dN/dt = β_0-β_1N$.

In short, you did everything right and your source is wildly switching the sign while professing to want to avoid that.

Comment: Thanks! Now I understand the sign of $\beta _1$. Yet I am confused why ${N_{t - 1}}$ becomes $N$ after Step 4? I think ${N_{t - 1}}$ is different from $N$, since $N$ can be ${N_{t - 1}}$ or ${N_{t}}$, but ${N_{t}}$ has its only value.

Comment: $N$ is a continuous function, for $Δt\approx0$ you get $N(t)\approx N(t-Δt)$. This is probably also a case of abuse of notation, a counting index should not be called $t$, if in the next step the time is also called $t$. It really makes no sense that indices $(t-1,t)$ correspond to times $(t-Δt,t)$.